# Error downloading data from internet in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to download some data from the internet to work with `Text Mining` in `R`, but running the command fails.

The commands are:

```
url <- 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt' 
arquivo <- read.csv(url)
```

And the error is:

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string 1
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

I tried several arguments for `read.csv()` function, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string 1
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

is telling you there is non-text data in the stream. Upon inspection this appears to be a GZ-encoded stream, which a web browser would decode on the fly to present the plain text. R might not want to do that. You can get the plain text version from this URL

```
> txt = readLines("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt")
> txt[14532]
[1] "ADRIANA. To fetch my poor distracted husband hence."
> txt[143532]
[1] "    He looks like sooth. He says he loves my daughter;"
```

Comment: The online course instructor who is doing, progressing download the data without problems. I'm using `Linux Manjaro`, can that be it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a text (.txt) document from project Gutenberg. Use readLines

```
url <- 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt' 
arquivo <- readLines(url)
```

This works for me

Comment: This gives me warnings about embedded nul characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` package `readr` is an option:

```
arquivo <- readr::read_file(url)
```